# rsvg with Python 3.2 on Ubuntu

Tags: python, svg, python-3.x, cairo, rsvg

I am trying to use rsvg in Python 3.2 but I keep getting an import error. I have installed all of the librsvg packages along with cairo. I cannot find anything online about what else to install to get it to work. I did hear that the rsvg module hasn't been updated since 2005 so is it just not compatible with Python 3.2, or is there something else I can try to install it? Alternatively, if rsvg does not work, does anyone have any suggestions for a simple way to display an SVG file through Python (basically just show the image)?

EDIT: The error I get is: 'ImportError: No module named rsvg'

This error does not show in python2

Thanks in advance

Comment: What error are you getting? Can you add it to your question?

Comment: I think PyQt should be capable of displaying an SVG image. It works with Python 3 - look for the package `python3-pyqt4`.

Comment: You could wrap it through `ctypes`, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/14943090/1832154. I have to install a huge amount of packages in order to get the python bindings for it, so I just use `ctypes` when I rarely need it.

Answer (score 18):

I experienced a lot of difficulty trying to figure out how to do this. I hope others find this answer and save themselves a lot of time!

For Python 3, Python language bindings for several libraries originally written in C (including [GTK](http://www.gtk.org/), [Clutter](http://blogs.gnome.org/clutter/), and [librsvg](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Projects/LibRsvg)) have been replaced by [GObject introspection](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Projects/GObjectIntrospection) libraries, Python code which dynamically generates Python objects from C "objects".

In order to use `librsvg` on Python 3, first install the necessary GObject introspection libraries (in addition to the Python 3 Cairo library). For example, on Ubuntu 13.10:

```
sudo apt-get install gir1.2-rsvg-2.0 python3-cairo python-gi-cairo python3-gi
```

Then test it out with the following code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3                                                          

# `gi.repository` is a special Python package that dynamically generates objects
import gi
gi.require_version('Rsvg', '2.0')
from gi.repository import Rsvg
import cairo

INPUTFILE = 'tiger.svg'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # create the cairo context                                                  
    surface = cairo.SVGSurface('myoutput.svg', 580, 530)
    context = cairo.Context(surface)

    # use rsvg to render the cairo context                                      
    handle = Rsvg.Handle()
    svg = handle.new_from_file(INPUTFILE)
    svg.render_cairo(context)
```

In order to implement this for your project,

1. change `cairo.SVGSurface` to be whatever surface you are going to draw on, and
2. modify the value of `INPUTFILE` to be the name of the SVG file you wish to render.

Comment: Also `sudo apt-get install python3-gi` and, in Python: `from gi import require_version` and `require_version('Rsvg', '2.0')` before `from gi.repository import Rsvg`.

Comment: On Ubuntu 18, even with all those packages installed, I get the error, `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gi'`