# Create cairo path from SVG file

Tags: python, windows, svg, cairo, pycairo

There must be something I am missing.

I am on Windows and want to use python to take the paths from a SVG-file, scale them an place every single one of them on a new surface (or all on one, that doesn't really matter).

I read about cairo [here](http://cairographics.org/tutorial/) and [on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6589358/convert-svg-to-png-in-python) and it seemed to me, that it would fit my needs, but I could not find an easy way to generate a path from a svg file. Is there no easier solution than parsing the SVG by hand eg. with xml?

Comment: I just answered a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10393675/rsvg-with-python-3-2-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

CairoSVG parses SVG files and renders them to cairo: http://cairosvg.org/

If you only want a single path, it should be possible to use just the right functions from CairoSVG. Feel free to ask on [the tracker](https://github.com/Kozea/CairoSVG/issues)

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

I came across cairosvg earlier and because I could not find what I wanted in the documentation, I continued to read threw and extend it. But I had stop  at some point, because I could not see the mountain tip after three days I spend on it. Do you have further knowledge about cairosvg?

So I am now using Inkscape in shell mode. More of a quick and dirty solution than a good one, but it works.