# Transform svg image into Luxor/Javis path

Tags: svg, julia

I have a svg image like this:

[image]

And I want to transform it in a path, so I can use `pathtopoly()` and do stuff with it, numerically. Namely, make it be drawn with Fourier transforms.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR I don't think there is a straightforward way to do this. You'd need a way of converting an SVG to a Cairo path, which I don't believe exists in Julia at the moment. There is [CairoSVG](https://github.com/Kozea/CairoSVG) in Python which renders SVG files to a Cairo surface. You might be able to use [PyCall](https://github.com/JuliaPy/PyCall.jl) if you can find the appropriate documentation in CairoSVG for what you're looking to do (although this was not a feature in [a previous (very old) thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13709243/create-cairo-path-from-svg-file) on a similar topic).